# How to create xml from struct in rust?

Tags: rust, serde

I try to create a xml string from a struct in rust. The struct is nested and I'm always getting duplicate tags in xml.
I'm using serde-xml-rs version 0.5.1.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct A {
   #[serde(rename(serialize = "B"))]
   pub b: B
}

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct B {
    pub c: String
}

let foo = A {
    b: B {
        c: "bar".to_string()
    }
};

println!("{:?}", to_string(&foo));
```

This produces

```
<A>
    <B>
        <B>
            <c>bar</c>
        </B>
    </B>
</A>
```

What I expect:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <c>bar</c>
    </B>
</A>
```

How can I get just one B tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `B` struct to avoid it emitting a `<B>` tag like this:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct B {
    pub c: String,
    #[serde(flatten, skip)]
    pub _d: (),
}
```